# Moving Between Multiple XIB Files

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-animation

It's my understanding that in order to move between xib files one usually uses
either a Navigation Controller, Tab Controller, or Flipside Controller or combination of them.

But my question is- can I write my own custom controller, and use Core Animation to move between Views or are these default controllers (navigation/tab/flipside) the only options to transition between xib files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.  One way to do this is to have a root level view controller, call it RootViewController, that knows about the child view controllers.  Then it's just a matter of setting up and running an animation block that removes one childViewController's view from RootViewController and adds another childViewController's view to RootViewController.  The animation block would probably be triggered from some action method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a rootController, in that situation you're gonna use

> /* RootController */
>
> - (void) showSomething:(id)_example {
>     self.view = somethingController.view;    //Setting your view
>     somethingController.example = _example;  //You can even set property between your views
>     }

/* UIViewController+RootControllerAccess */

// .H

> import "RootController.h"
>
> @interface UIViewController (RootControllerAccess)
>      -(RootController *) rootController;
>   @end

// .M

> import "UIViewController+RootControllerAccess.h"
>
> @implementation UIViewController (RootControllerAccess)
>
> -(RootController*) fadeController{
>      return (RootController *)self.view.window.rootViewController;
>   }
>
> @end

/* Here you go, you're set to call any views any where

> by doing this you can use anywhere showSomething : [self.rootController showSomething:nil];